# Open Classifieds Permission issues

Tags: php, file-permissions

When attempting to upload a picture I get an error "Directory not writeable"

In logs I get:

> 2016-09-22 00:00:22 --- ERROR: Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory must
>   be writable:  ~ APPPATH/kohana/modules/image/classes/Kohana/Image.php
>   [ 633 ] in
>   /home/oddsnend/public_html/oc/kohana/system/classes/Kohana/Kohana/Exception.php:110

I am having issues finding which  directory needs to be writeable as it does not explicitly say. Please help me troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

These directories must be writable for Open Classifieds:

```
/oc/cache
/oc/logs
/images
```

These are the commands copied from [Open Classified documentation](https://docs.yclas.com/change-folder-permissions/).

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/ww/openclassifieds/oc/cache
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /var/ww/openclassifieds/oc/cache
```

I'm not sure why their documentation left out the `755`—I'm not aware of `chmod` working that way, so I included it.

The documentation also mentions clearing the cache if there are any errors:

```
sudo rm -f /var/ww/openclassifieds/oc/cache
```

Comment: The paths you have provided are not working. I keep getting "No such file or directory". I have installed open classifieds on a VPS with cpanel, if this changes anything.

Comment: I did try and edit the path you provided by navigating into the directory manually and the commands worked, but the error still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here Chema, Open Classifieds founder ;)

You can always use our forums for help: https://forums.open-classifieds.com/

Also we have a 1 file installation that will check all the requirements for your installation:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-classifieds/openclassifieds2/master/install-openclassifieds.php

But as mentioned by Andrew changing the permission sohuld work. Thanks for pointing the permissions issue in the docs, was missing xD

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried to navigate to the install-open.php script and it just comes back with: Unable to find a route to match the URI: install-openclassifieds.php

Comment: please use our forum we will help you there, we have also extensive documentation about how to install. takes less than a minute: https://docs.yclas.com/install-open-classifieds/

Comment: or you can just simply use Yclas.com ;)